# Erhu vibrato before Western contact?

Tags: history, vibrato, erhu

Was vibrato known as a technique in China before the introduction of Western string instruments? How common was it to use vibrato when performing the erhu?

Comment: I'd be interested in any ref's to papers on the history of erhu playing styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vibrato was and is known as two different techniques: Rou Xian and Yaxian. The below excerpt from [Samuel Wong's erhu research](http://www.atlasensemble.nl/assets/files/instruments/Erhu/Erhu%20by%20Samuel%20Wong%20Shengmiao.pdf) explains the two techniques:

> 揉弦 Rou Xian (Vibrato)
>
> Vibratos can be effected by:
>
> i. Using finger pressure to suppress the string, increasing and decreasing its tension. This technique is also known as 压弦 yaxian and this is possible as the instrument has no fingerboard;
>
> ii. Moving the wrist up and down while pressing at the strings, affecting the finger surface that presses the string;
>
> iii.   Using the above two methods together;
>
> iv. Using little or no finger pressure, but instead, locking one’s finger joints and lifting one’s elbow, and sliding the locked finger up and down the string. Such a technique is used in pieces like 河南小曲 He Nan Xiao Qu and 喜唱丰收 Xi Chang Feng Shou.  This technique is commonly termed 滑柔 huarou.
>
> Yaxian  is  more  popular  in  folk  music  while  the  wrist  method  is  more
>   commonly used by stringed instruments in the Chinese orchestra.
>   Rouxian is considered the pivot of some erhu repertoire. In the piece 江河水 >Jiang He Shui (River 
>   Waters), a combination of rouxian is used. The fingers apply a lot of pressure >on the strings but 
>   strong wrist movements are in place simultaneously, creating a melancholic >sound texture.  The 
>   usage of rouxian is determined by the   erhu
>   player himself, it may be indicated on a score with a ‘﹋﹋’ above the note.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Elaine_Chew3/publication/257931904_Vibrato_Performance_Style_A_Case_Study_Comparing_Erhu_and_Violin/links/00b7d5264ca5ac9683000000.pdf

http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luwei_Yang2/publication/278158431_Vibrato_Characteristics_and_Frequency_Histogram_Envelopes_in_Beijing_Opera_Singing/links/557ca18108ae26eada8c9f30.pdf

http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luwei_Yang2/publication/263322998_CROSS-CULTURAL_COMPARISONS_OF_EXPRESSIVITY_IN_RECORDED_ERHU_AND_VIOLIN_MUSIC_PERFORMER_VIBRATO_STYLES/links/0046353a93e9d566cf000000.pdf

Perhaps these will be of assistance.

Comment: It's considered proper form to discuss and quote pertinent sections of linked information.

Comment: Precisely; suppose your links cease to function someday (links aren't permanent). Your answer is simply a string of semirandom characters underlined in blue, should that occur.